# Go Top a TVertScrollBox

Tags: delphi-xe8

If a user has scrolled down in a VertScrollBox, how do I set it back to the top position again in XE8?

this code don't Work on XE8

```
VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition := PointF(0,0);
VertScrollBox1.RealignContent
```

Answer (score 4):

```
VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition := PointF(VertScrollBox1.ViewportPosition.X, 0);
```

Works for me on Android and Windows.

Comment: In XE10.1 works too, thank you, I had the same problem.